# On a type of stability for irrational rotation

Tags: dynamical-systems, set-partition, stability-theory

I hope you can give me some suggestion.

**Definition**: Given two bijections $f,g:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1$ and $\mathcal{P}$ a partition of $\mathbb{S}^1$ (a partition of $\mathbb{S}^1$ is a finite disjoint collection of nonempty subsets  whose union is $\mathbb{S}^1$). We say that $f$ and $g$ are $\mathcal{P}$-close if for every $x\in \mathbb{S}^1$ the set $\{f(x),g(x)\}$ is contained in a element of $\mathcal{P}$.

Let $R:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1$ be a rotation such that $R(x)=(x+\frac{1}{\pi}) \mod\ 1$.

**I would like to know if $R$ satisfies the following property:** Given a partition $\mathcal{P}$, there exists a partition $\mathcal{Q}$ such that if $g:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1$ is a bijection $\mathcal{Q}$-close with $R$ then there is a map $h:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1$ such that

- $h\circ g=R\circ h$
- $h$ is $\mathcal{P}$-close with the identity map $I$ in $\mathbb{S}^1$.

**Note:** The identity map $I$ satisfies that property. In fact, given $\mathcal{P}=\{A_1,\cdots,A_k\}$ is suffcient to take $\mathcal{Q}=\mathcal{P}$. Let $g:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1$ be a bijection $\mathcal{Q}$-close with $I$. Fix a finite collection $\{a_1,\cdots,a_k\}$ where $a_i\in A_i$. Hence the map $h:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1$ such that $h(y)=g(a_i)$ whenever $y\in A_i$ satisfies: $h\circ g=h$ and it is $\mathcal{P}$-close with $I$.

Comment: Would this work as a trivial example? For any $\mathcal{P}$, take $\mathcal{Q}$ to be the set of all singletons in $S^1$.  Whenever $g$ is $\mathcal{Q}$-close with $R$, then necessarily $g=R$ and so $h=I$ has the desired properties. (Or are there other conditions to include?)

Comment: It does not work since each partition is a finite set of subsets. Thus $\{\{x\}:  x\in S^1\}$ is not a partition.

Comment: Note that if $h$ is $\mathcal P'$-close to the identity and $\mathcal P'$ is a refinement of $\mathcal P$, then $h$ is $\mathcal P$-close to the identity. That means by implication that the easiest non-trivial case is where $$\mathcal P = \{A,B\}.$$ I've been thinking about $\mathcal P = \big\{\{x\},S^1\backslash \{x\}\big\}$, (so we are requiring that $h(x) = x$) but to no avail!